# Which mobile operating systems support J2ME?

Tags: java-me, wurfl

I've been tasked with using WURFUL to determine whether or not a mobile browser is capable of downloading a J2ME app developed by my company.

I first thought I could use the "device_os" tag and filter by that, however, I'm unsure what the complete list of J2ME OS's are... any ideas?

I've been told there are no MIDP requirements, and that the application will run on any J2ME-supported handset (with two specific resolutions, which I already know how to query)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to know all the OSes that support J2ME. Mainly because most feature handset comes with a proprietary OS which probably you have never seen before. It is a better idea try to identify the handset model and decide if it supports J2ME or not.

Another thing is, you may want to know which JSRs are supported by a specific handset. I do not know your application but probably you are using some optional JSRs that are not supported by some handsets although they have basic J2ME support.

[Java ME SDK 3.0](http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/sdk30.jsp) includes a database of supported devices. Also there are other web sites that provides these kind of information. One example to those would be this [J2ME Handsets](http://www.j2mehandsets.com/) web site.

If you are fine with just covering a large range of phones, you should include Symbian S60, S40, Windows Mobile, Blackberry and Android.

Answer (score 1):

Symbian
Win Mob
Android
Almost every Sonyericsson phones

IMHO you don't have to worry about how many handsets support j2me because majority of the phones support it.

Answer (score 0):

At least Symbian and Android.