# J2ME Application how many mobile operating systems supports

Tags: java-me

I need to develop on mobile application in J2ME, So i need to know J2ME mobile application how my mobile operating systems supports Please give me the reply

thanks
upendra

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029769/which-mobile-operating-systems-support-j2me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The J2ME Polish Device Database might give you some insight:

http://devices.j2mepolish.org/interactivedb/welcome.faces